# webpack lektor bootstrap scss @import paths

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack, lektor

I am attempting to use bootstrap with lektor.

Following the instructions found [here](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/guides/webpack/), everything worked as expected. I then used `npm` to install `jquery` and `bootstrap`.

"Requiring" jquery and bootstrap in `webpack/js/main.js` works without a hitch. However when I attempted to

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

in `webpack/scss/main.scss` I got the following:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./scss/main.scss
    Module build failed: 
    @import "bootstrap";
    ^
          File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
    Parent style sheet: stdin
          in /home/lysdexia/Projects/thing/webpack/scss/main.scss (line 4, column 1)
```

This lead me to a bunch of not-very-helpful reading vis the node search path. I found that all three of the the following:

```
@import "/home/lysdexia/Projects/thing/webpack/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootsrap.css";
@import "/bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.css";
@import "/bootstrap.css";
```

. . . all *seem* to import without errors. All the scss examples show a simple `@import whatever;` which I now suspect may be shorthand for something, or an assumption of a different configuration.

Unfortunately, upon attempting to `@extend` a class with a bootstrap class gives me a `The selector ".row" was not found.`, which says to me that the import didn't actually work, and failed without an error.

I must admit some embarrassment and confusion here. Is there a way to examine node's search paths? It seems somewhat logical (if a bit wishy-washy) that "/" can mean "full path from root" or "my paths start in node_modules", but why `/bootstrap.css` would even appear to work is just bizarre.